# Proper way to install Application Insights in a Windows 8.1 Javascript app

Tags: windows-8.1, winjs, win-universal-app, azure-application-insights

I have a Windows 8.1 universal app written using javascript and would like to install application insights to capture telemetry data.

I've followed the instructions [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-javascript/) and installed the Application Insights for Javascript Apps nuget package in my project.

It's partially working. I see page views coming through and some (but not all) of the exceptions I'm tracking using calls to `appInsights.trackException`. I don't get any crash reports.

Is there something I'm missing that's preventing crash reports and exceptions from being tracked? Is this the correct way to setup Application Insights for Windows 8.1 javascript apps?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. There doesn't seem to be much information out there on this scenario.

Comment: It seems AI is not ready for Windows JavaScript Apps yet. I can't get it to work using the nuget package they offer.

Answer (score 0):

We don't support JavaScript for devices. Sorry.